# SSL Certificate "Issued by" modified by server

Tags: .net, ssl, certificate

We have a .Net application that connects to web services on servers that we host, and we have SSL certificates bound to https/443 on those servers.  Sometimes these SSL certificates are self-signed, so we're not relying entirely on the X509Certificate2.Verify() method and the SslPolicyErrors.None enum within the method that we've programmed for ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, because our certs aren't always valid.

We have a secondary step that checks the signature of the hash string (X509Certificate.GetCertHashString()) and compares it against a list of "approved" certificates.  This way we can return a true for the callback if it's a known certificate.

In one of our installation sites, we're getting a different hash string when connecting to precisely the same web server.  After printing out to a log file every property on the X509Certificate object, I found that the "Issued By" value is different when they connect.  Something along the way from their users' workstations out to their network hardware, and then off to our server, is modifying the certificate.  When our application validates the certificate, first of all it's not a trusted authority anymore, and second when it checks the hash string, it's not on the approved list (changing the issuer seems to change the hash).

Can anyone provide any ideas on how they're doing this?  Furthermore, any idea how to do that programmatically in .Net?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the connections in question are being intercepted by an enterprise proxy like [bluecoat](http://www.bluecoat.com/) or [websense](http://www.websense.com/) that's middling the SSL session?

Answer (score 0):

Altering the certificate would break its signature, and as your validation shows that something alters the certificate, you should look at *what* changes the certificate, not "how" it's done.

The change is simple - as the certificate is self-signed, someone can just create another self-signed certificate with his own keypair and put different Subject or Issuer to the certificate. Not a big deal. The goal is obviously to capture and decode the traffic by installing man-in-the-middle proxy.